# How to Restore data from binary log

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

How can I restore my files and photos from binary files?

Answer (score 11):

Do you know from which binlog files you need to restore and how many binlog files there are?

Using `mysqlbinlog` utility we can view the binlog file content.

If it's a single file you can recover using:

```
mysqlbinlog /var/lib/mysql-bin.000016 | mysql –uroot –pReset123
```

If it's multiple files then just extract all content to one .sql file and directly restore it:

```
mysqlbinlog /var/lib/mysql-bin.000016 > /logs/allbinlog.sql
```

To append second binlog content to allbinlof.sql file use below command:

```
mysqlbinlog /var/lib/mysql-bin.000016 >> /logs/allbinlog.sql
```

You can also exclude certain statements using option of mysqlbinlog. Try this below for options:

```
mysqlbinlog --help
```

Answer (score 9):

Use below steps to restore data from binary logs or use this link to understand restoration process: [**MySQL Binary Log Restoration**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/point-in-time-recovery.html)

First, restore database from the latest backup

```
mysql -u username -ppassword database_name < dump.sql
```

Then do either of:

- Restore rest of data from binary log.

  If you have more than one binary log to execute on the MySQL server, the safe method is to process them all using a single connection to the server.

  ```
  mysqlbinlog mysql_bin.000001 | mysql -u root -ppassword database_name
  mysqlbinlog mysql_bin.000002 | mysql -u root -ppassword database_name
  ```

  or:

  ```
  mysqlbinlog mysql_bin.000001 mysql_bin.000002 | mysql -u root -ppassword database_name
  ```
- Restore data on basis of time

  ```
  mysqlbinlog --start-datetime="2005-04-20 10:01:00" \
              --stop-datetime="2005-04-20 9:59:59" mysql_bin.000001 \
              | mysql -u root -ppassword database_name
  ```
- Restore data on basis of position

  ```
  mysqlbinlog --start-position=368315 \
              --stop-position=368312 mysql_bin.000001 \
              | mysql -u root -ppassword database_name
  ```

Comment: The first example of restoring more than one binary log is specifically unsafe, as noted in the documentation.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, it should be noted that the binlog files contain changes of a database for a time interval, but they do **not include ALL data**, and it makes no sense to restore only the binlog files. As a rule, to restore a database you need a full backup, and all binlog files that were created after a full backup. **To restore data from binlog files, you need to perform a full backup correctly.**

```
mysqldump -u root -ppassword --flush-logs --delete-master-logs  --all-databases > full-backup.sql
```

There are two important parameters in the command:

`--flush-logs` - this parameter starts writing to a new binlog file.

`--delete-master-logs` - removes old binlog files

Thus, in the folder with binary logs there will be only binlog files created after a full backup.

To restore data, firstly you have to restore a full backup

```
mysql -u root -ppassword  < full-backup.sql
```

And then restore all the binlog files via mysqlbinlog utility, specifying the paths to the binlog files (the order is important).

```
mysqlbinlog  mysql_bin.000023 mysql_bin.000024 mysql_bin.000025 | mysql -u root -ppassword
```

--

Note, if you use master\slave replication, then you should not use `--delete-master-logs` when performing a full backup on the master server, as this can [break replication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644711/mysqldump-delete%20-master-logs-safe-for-replication)

But in this case, you have to remember which particular binlog file was created the `--flush-log` parameter, and for the restore process use it and all the binlog files that were created later.

More details about how to backup and restore incremental backups can be found at [this article](https://sqlbak.com/blog/incremental-mysql-server-backup-via-binary-log)

Answer (score 3):

You can use **-v** option to make .sql file in **READABLE** format.

For Example

```
mysqlbinlog -v /var/lib/mysql-bin.000016 > /logs/allbinlog.sql

mysqlbinlog -v /var/lib/mysql-bin.000016 >> /logs/allbinlog.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `binlog` with [`binlog_format=ROW`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_binlog_format) which both is by default as of mysql 8.0,

and haven't done a full backup within the lifespan of available `binlog` files, i.e. complete `mysqldump` after the configured time of [`binlog_expire_logs_seconds`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_binlog_expire_logs_seconds) before now, to perform the suggested [Point-in-Time Recovery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/point-in-time-recovery-positions.html),

then you can still try to recover deleted rows with only a `binlog` file that covers these deleted events and turn them into insert events with this approach in https://github.com/lefred/MyUndelete/issues/5 :

> it's able to replace the event type with the original awk script in http://thenoyes.com/littlenoise/?p=307:
>
> ```
> BEGIN { regexp = "$^" }
>
> /^BINLOG/ {
>   print;
>   getline;
>   regexp = "^" substr($0, 1, 5) "[CSiy][ABCD]" substr($0, 8, 4);
> }
>
> $0 ~ regexp {
>   n = $0;
>   $0 = substr(n, 1, 5)
>   $0 = $0 substr("BRhx", index("CSiy", substr(n, 6, 1)), 1)
>   $0 = $0 substr("4567", index("ABCD", substr(n, 7, 1)), 1)
>   $0 = $0 substr(n, 8) ;
> }
>
> { print; }
> ```
>
> ```bash
> sudo mysqlbinlog --start-position=148418658 --stop-position=484776616 binlog.000117 | awk -f undelete.awk | mysql
> ```