# Resume MySQL / MariaDB replication from master logs

Tags: mysql, mariadb, replication

Master server crashed and slave was running behind. I can not boot the master to resume the replication and retrieve the data lost. Is there a way to resume the replication directly from the log files?

Replication shows:

```
show all slaves status
...
Master_Log_File: mariadb-bin.124609
```

And the master data folder shows 150 binlogs after mariadb-bin.124609.

Thanks,

Comment: This solved my question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29414/how-to-restore-data-from-binary-log

Comment: Was I/O stopped before the crash?  That is, was that Replica really caught up before?

Comment: @RickJames yes. slave was down.